# Visual C# 2010 Express keeps File Handle after Debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp

After debug, in about 90% of the cases I can't rebuild my solution, because VS keeps the file handle of the old .exe (can't copy the new exe from obj\Debug to bin\Debug). I know that it's VS's file handle for sure, since I checked it with the Unlocker Assistent. Also, I tried the workaround with calling the default namespace the same es the executable, but no luck. Any ideas?

PS: Running it on Windows XP.

Comment: Is your program still running?  Use Taskmgr.exe, Processes tab.

Comment: nope, only the associated <myappname>.vhost.exe is still running, the application itself is not

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug in VS since 2005. A google search will show MANY posts about this problem that Microsoft has yet to address. It hits me every so often as well when the IDE won't let go of a dll. Unfortunately a restart of VS is required :(